# Как учитывать поселение вызванный метод или свойства последнего указанного, как избавится от дубликатов?

Tags: php, ооп

Вот пример.

```js
class loadTemplate {

    public function load($title = ""){
    
      echo "<title>".$title."</title>";
    
    }
    
}
```

```html
$loadPage = new loadTemplate();
$loadPage->load("1");

$loadPage->load("2");

$loadPage->load("3");
```

В результате вывод будет 1 2 3 как сделать так чтобы приняло только последний параметр 3

Comment: В чём смысл? Устанавливайте значение сеттерами и после этого отображайте

Comment: Это как? Я учусь. Не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Это [как-то так](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba118e7bef0a13d7aaf19b4b5730209c3b986e29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
class loadTemplate {
    private $title;

    //сеттер
    public function setTitle($title = ""){
    
      $this->title = $title;
    
    }

    //getter - вдруг понадобится
    public function getTitle(){
    
      return $this->title;
    
    }

    public function out(){
    
      echo $this->getTitle(); //либо сразу $this->title;
    
    }

    
}
```

Дальше просто

```php
$loadPage = new loadTemplate();
$loadPage->setTitle("1");

$loadPage->setTitle("2");

$loadPage->setTitle("3");

$loadPage->out();
```